# Is proof a quantifiable word?

Tags: quantifiers

Can I quantify the word "proof", so is it possible to write the phrase *many proofs* and if yes in which situation is this more appropriate than writing *much proof*?

Comment: Have a look at [this definition of *proof* (definition 1)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proof). It can be used either as a mass noun or as a count noun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, proof can be quantifiable. One obvious context is the realm of mathematics, where there may be more than one proof of a theorem. So, for example, one could say:

> There aren't many proofs for the four-colored map problem.
>   Many early proofs of Fermat's last theorem were found to contain errors.

On the other hand, *proof* is sometimes used in a way similar to *evidence*. (One might argue that *evidence* would be a better word to use in such situations, but the fact remains that *proof* is nevertheless used.) For example, in [this science editorial](http://www.azocleantech.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=265), the author wrote:

> There is much proof that Mars was once, if not a green planet, a planet that once held flowing water and possibly life.

Both can be used; it really depends on if you're talking about a body of evidence or individual proofs.

As a footnote, other usages of the word *proof* are clearly quantifiable, such as:

> The photographer gave us nine proofs to choose from.

Comment: Good photo proof example -- I hadn't recalled the use "an advanced copy for checking."

Comment: The author of the second citation should not have written "once" twice. Other trivium: a proof with an error is not a proof, so the "many early proofs" in the first citation were in fact none.

Comment: @Marc - I considered putting "proofs" in scare quotes for that reason. (I debated it for a couple minutes, actually.) In the end, though, I opted for simplicity, as have [many authors before me](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X#q=%22erroneous+proof%22&safe=off&hl=en&tbm=bks).

Comment: I believe it is the four color *theorem*. The map problem is "how many colors?" The theorem is "four." Someone proves a theorem, not a problem: you could prove "P=NP", but cannot prove "the P vs. NP problem." Funny that we chose the same example.

Comment: @JeremyD - I think it can be called [either one](https://www.britannica.com/topic/four-color-map-problem). Perhaps some of us old geezers inadvertantly fall back on _problem_ because we remember when it was still unproven :-)

Comment: @J.R. fair enough! I was not tuned in to such matters pre-1977. :) In the general case would you agree that "I proved the problem" or "That is a proof of the problem" etc. fits poorly with the usage of 'proof' in this context? Proving a problem has a meaning in English usage that is different from a solution.

Comment: @JeremyD - Yes, I agree; "I proved the problem" may be grammatical, but it does sound awkward, particularly from a mathematics perspective.